# Complement to the Gompertz function

Tags: functions, monotone-functions, reflection

From the wikipedia article on the [Gompertz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_function): "The right-hand or future value asymptote of the function is approached much more gradually by the curve than the left-hand or lower valued asymptote."

Is there a sigmoidal, asymmetrical function, similar to the Gompertz, so that the behaviour at the asymptotes are reversed, that is: The right-hand or future value asymptote of the function is approached much more **rapidly** by the curve than the left-hand or lower valued asymptote.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one parameter in the Gompertz, namely *β*,
$$
x(t)= e^{-\beta e^{-t}},
$$
satisfying
$$ \frac{dx}{dt}= (\ln x) ~x,
$$
since the other two customary parameters provide scale normalizations for the flow of time and the height of the asymptotic value, here taken to be 1.  But if you take $\beta=\ln 2$, the origin of time is at the half-value of the function.

All you need to do is flip the graph of the function left-to-right and upside down,  and shift vertically by 1,
$$
y=1-e^{-\ln 2 ~ e ^t}.
$$